# jQuery if an element has class do

Tags: jquery, html

I need an jQuery script that will add my `img` class `hidden` when one of my html element (for example `"#3"`) has class `active`.

I did it like:

html script:

```
 <ul class="navUl" id="menu">
  <li class="navi head" id="1">x</li>
  <li class="navi head" id="2">y</li>
  <li class="navi head" id="3">q</li>
  <li class="navi head" id="4">w</li>
  <li class="navi head" id="5">e</li>
 </ul>

 <img src="img/cover.png" alt="cover" class="cover" id="cover">
```

jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#3').hasClass('active', function () {
  $('#cover').addClass('hidden');
 });
});
```

P.S.  I've already had jQuery script and it's working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#menu li').on('click', function(){
  $('#menu li.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
 });
});
```

Comment: Are you saying you did it, and it's working, or do you have a question ?

Comment: @adeneo i think it's working it is the meaning for only active class. not for applying hidden class in img tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple, You can just validate that target element has class in `li` event handler, then perform the desired operation

```
$('#menu li').on('click', function() {
    $('#menu li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    $('#cover').toggleClass('hidden', $('#3').hasClass('active'));
});
```

Otherwise, Use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and listen for attribute change

```js
$('#menu li').on('click', function() {
  $('#menu li.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});

var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

var element = $('#3').get(0);
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type == "attributes") {
      $('#cover').toggleClass('hidden', $('#3').hasClass('active'));
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(element, {
  attributes: true //configure it to listen to attribute changes
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}

.hidden {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="navUl" id="menu">
  <li class="navi head" id="1">x</li>
  <li class="navi head" id="2">y</li>
  <li class="navi head" id="3">q</li>
  <li class="navi head" id="4">w</li>
  <li class="navi head" id="5">e</li>
</ul>

<img src="img/cover.png" alt="cover" class="cover" id="cover">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this example.

Hope this will helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#menu li').on('click', function(){
   $('#menu li.active').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   
   if($(this).attr("id") == "3") {
     $("#cover").addClass('hidden');
   } else {
      $("#cover").removeClass('hidden');
   }
   
 });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navUl" id="menu">
  <li class="navi head" id="1">x</li>
  <li class="navi head" id="2">y</li>
  <li class="navi head" id="3">q</li>
  <li class="navi head" id="4">w</li>
  <li class="navi head" id="5">e</li>
 </ul>

 <img src="img/cover.png" alt="cover" class="cover" id="cover">
```

Comment: Perfect, it helped me! Thank you very mutch! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this. Hope this will help you

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if($('#3').hasClass('active')) {
   $('#cover').hide() 
  }  
})
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/abinthaha/pen/QMLmjp)